# Does "In the room is cool." make sense?

Tags: grammaticality

I want to know if the following sentence makes sense.

> In the room is cool.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELL.SE! To help us answer your question, please edit your question to include some context. For example, are you talking about the temperature in the room, or something else?

Comment: Also, what about this sentence are you unsure of? What is the meaning you expect it to have?

Comment: I mean temperature in the room.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this sentence does not have a subject. English is [non-pro-drop language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-drop_language), in which the subject cannot be dropped, unlike other languages, such as Spanish or French.  Here, *it* is a [dummy pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletive_pronoun) or expletive.
So you can say

> In the room, it is cool.

or

> It is cool in the room.

Answer (score 1):

If that's a complete sentence, then no. There is no sense of who or what is being talked about. Now, if it said "Everyone in the room is cool" then that's a perfectly good sentence. Or if you are talking about the room itself, then "The room is cool" would work.

Comment: Or, "In the room, everything is cool." Or, "It is cool in the room."

Comment: It could make sense, say in response to a question like "Should I put this item in the hall or in the room?" "In the room is cool". We definitely need some context from the OP though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a native speaker, but I can imagine this being a valid answer to, for example, "would you like to have dinner in the kitchen, or in the room?"
or
"Shall I bring it (whatever) upstairs, or shall I leave it here in the room?"
where "the room" can be the living room or bedroom or any room, that's not relevant, it's assumed they know what the room is.
The person answering replies that it's cool (OK) to have/leave it in "the" room.
So cool is not about temperature, it just means OK.

It might not be a 100% correct full English sentence, but the question was whether it makes sense, so I would say yes it can.